# How to get Visual Studios build system to understand unmanaged dependencies of managed dlls?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, dependencies, unmanaged, managed

When building managed code Visual Studio correctly (and recursively) copies dlls of referenced managed projects to the output folder of the project being build.

However, if one the of those references is a managed DLL that depends on unmanaged dlls then these unmanaged DLLs are not copied to the output folder, even though their corresponding projects in the same solution and are listed as dependencies of the managed DLL.

I realize that this problem can be resolved by having all projects use the same output folder. We already do that for most projects, but we prefer to keep unit test output folders separate, causing the above issue for unit tests that use a managed Dll with unmanaged dependencies.

The solution we are using right now is a pre-build event to copy the necessary DLLs but this wastes time and is error-prone as it needs to be repeated for every project that uses the managed DLL.

I would therefore like to know if there is a way to get the build system to understand that it should always copy the unmanaged dependencies of the managed DLL whenever it decides to copy the managed DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One workaround seems to be to add another node to the managed DLL project, naming the unmanaged DLL and setting the Build Action = "None", and Copy to Output Directory = "Copy if Newer".

Edit: For building a C++/CLR project, I think this would work:

Add the node, and set its build tool to **Custom Build Tool**. Then, in the Custom Build Step page, set the *Command* to **copy $(InputPath) $(OutDir)** and the *Outputs* to **$(OutDir)\$(InputFileName)**. Looks like that should work.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent work-around. At least its managed in a single location in this way. Ill try it out as soon as i have time to make sure it works correctly.

I would however still be interested in whether there is a fully automated solution.

Comment: I believe the solution would work for managed C# projects. However the managed project in our scenario is a C++ CLR project. In C++ CLR projects there is no "Copy to output directory" property for project items like there is in C# projects.

Is there another way to specify such an action?

Comment: @Ziphnor: Edited my post to include a method that should work with C++/CLR projects.

Comment: Note that C++/CLI projects can also have a `<None Include="foo.dll"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory></None>` item manually edited into an `ItemGroup` of the project file, there's just no support for doing so through the property pages UI.