# How to link/reference unmanaged dependencies of a managed DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies, unmanaged, managed

My solution (in Visual Studio 2010) contains the following projects:

- **CppLibrary** : a native C++ library (generates a .lib)
- **CliLibrary** : a managed C++/CLI library that wraps the native C++ library (generates a .dll)
- **CsharpGUI**  : a C# GUI project that uses the managed library (generates an .exe)

In CliLibrary I link with *CppLibrary.lib*, and in CsharpGUI I have a reference to *CliLibrary.dll*. So far so good.

Now I have to use third-party libraries (OCCT) in my CppLibrary. The OCCT libraries to which I have access are either static (.lib) or dynamic (.dll). I tried the following approach:

1. In the CppLibrary properties, I added the path to OCCT include files (C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories)
2. In the CliLibrary properties, I provided required OCCT libraries (.lib) to the linker (Linker > General > Additional Library Directories, Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies)
3. I did not change anything in the CsharpGUI

In this state, my solution builds without error. However, at runtime, my application immediately throws the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'CliLibrary.dll' or one of its dependencies.

I assume the unmanaged OCCT libraries (which are dependencies of the managed CliLibrary) are not known/found at the CsharpGUI level. I thought the issue was addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980114/how-to-get-visual-studios-build-system-to-understand-unmanaged-dependencies-of-m) thread, but the proposed solution did not solve my problem. Following the idea in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496782/reference-an-unmanaged-c-dll-from-managed-c/14497705#14497705) thread, I tried to copy the required OCCT dlls in the same directory as CsharpGUI.exe, which did not solve the problem either.

Surely I am not the first one to cope with such a project/library hierarchy.

- How should I go about solving this problem?
- Am I using a wrong approach?

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" is the most obvious cue.  You *do* have new dependencies.  It is up to you to copy the DLL(s) in a place where the operating system can find them.  Only good place is in the same directory as the EXE, use a post-build event to copy them.  If you still have trouble then it might be a DLL that the native DLL needs.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see your program searching for it.  Or use a telephone.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your answer. As you suggested, DLLs needed by the third-party library were missing. How should I mark your comment as an answer to my question? I am new to the forum.